# Python. Максимальное значение словаря

Tags: python, словари, словарь

Дано список из 10 учениками и оценки из 10 предметов. Нужна программа, которая находит фамилию ученика с наибольшим и наименьшим количеством балов. Казалось, что вроде правильно всё, но программа не работает. Я так понимаю, что ошибка в цикле.
Вот мой код:

```
from collections import Counter
students={ 
'Трамп':{'Геометрія': 2,'Біологія': 3,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 3,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 2,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 5,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 2},
'Зеленський':{'Геометрія': 3,'Біологія': 3,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 3,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 2,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 5,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 2},
'Панасенко':{'Геометрія': 4,'Біологія': 4,'Англійська мова': 4,'Фізика': 4,'Алгебра': 1,'Українська мова': 3,'Хімія': 1,'Право': 2,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 5},
'Сухацький':{'Геометрія': 2,'Біологія': 1,'Англійська мова': 2,'Фізика': 1,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 2,'Хімія': 1,'Право': 2,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 1},
'Байда':{'Геометрія': 2,'Біологія':2,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 3,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 2,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 1,'Історія': 3,'Німецька мова': 3},
'Бородюх':{'Геометрія': 3,'Біологія': 4,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 1,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 1,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 5,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 2},
'Бучко':{'Геометрія': 4,'Біологія': 5,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 4,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 2,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 1,'Історія': 4,'Німецька мова': 4},
'Поліщук':{'Геометрія': 4,'Біологія': 3,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 5,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 1,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 5,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 4},
'Шевченко':{'Геометрія': 1,'Біологія': 3,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 3,'Алгебра': 3,'Українська мова': 5,'Хімія': 2,'Право': 3,'Історія': 4,'Німецька мова': 2},
'Горбач':{'Геометрія': 5,'Біологія': 5,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 5,'Алгебра': 5,'Українська мова': 5,'Хімія': 4,'Право': 4,'Історія': 5,'Німецька мова': 5}
            }

resultdict = {}                                
for name in students:
    for i in name:
        for key in i:                         
            resultdict[key] += i[key]     

print(resultdict)
print(max(resultdict))
print(min(resultdict))
```

Comment: "находит фамилию ученика с наибольшим и наименьшим количеством балов"... имеется ввиду сумма балов ученика?

Comment: Да, что бы в выводе был ученик, у кого наименьшее количество балов и ученик, с наибольшим количеством балов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
students={ 
    'Трамп':{'Геометрія': 2,'Біологія': 3,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 3,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 2,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 5,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 2},
    'Зеленський':{'Геометрія': 3,'Біологія': 3,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 3,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 2,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 5,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 2},
    'Панасенко':{'Геометрія': 4,'Біологія': 4,'Англійська мова': 4,'Фізика': 4,'Алгебра': 1,'Українська мова': 3,'Хімія': 1,'Право': 2,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 5},
    'Сухацький':{'Геометрія': 2,'Біологія': 1,'Англійська мова': 2,'Фізика': 1,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 2,'Хімія': 1,'Право': 2,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 1},
    'Байда':{'Геометрія': 2,'Біологія':2,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 3,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 2,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 1,'Історія': 3,'Німецька мова': 3},
    'Бородюх':{'Геометрія': 3,'Біологія': 4,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 1,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 1,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 5,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 2},
    'Бучко':{'Геометрія': 4,'Біологія': 5,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 4,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 2,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 1,'Історія': 4,'Німецька мова': 4},
    'Поліщук':{'Геометрія': 4,'Біологія': 3,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 5,'Алгебра': 2,'Українська мова': 1,'Хімія': 3,'Право': 5,'Історія': 1,'Німецька мова': 4},
    'Шевченко':{'Геометрія': 1,'Біологія': 3,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 3,'Алгебра': 3,'Українська мова': 5,'Хімія': 2,'Право': 3,'Історія': 4,'Німецька мова': 2},
    'Горбач':{'Геометрія': 5,'Біологія': 5,'Англійська мова': 5,'Фізика': 5,'Алгебра': 5,'Українська мова': 5,'Хімія': 4,'Право': 4,'Історія': 5,'Німецька мова': 5}
}

resultdict = {}                                
for name in students:
    resultdict[name] = 0
    for i in students[name]:             
        resultdict[name] += students[name][i] 

print(resultdict)
print(max(resultdict, key=lambda value:resultdict[value]))
print(min(resultdict, key=lambda value:resultdict[value]))
```

либо так:

```
print(max(students, key=lambda key:sum(students[key].values())))
print(min(students, key=lambda key:sum(students[key].values())))
```